# DBMS_XMLGEN.GETXMLTYPE with a bind variable

Tags: sql, oracle11g

Please see the SQL below, which works as expected:

```
SELECT '<System1 MAPPINGID="13" URN="2441">' || DBMS_XMLGEN.GETXMLTYPE ('SELECT * from image_data where IMAGE_DATA.DATE_CREATED >= TO_DATE(''2016-01-01'', ''YYYY-MM-DD'') 
AND IMAGE_DATA.DATE_CREATED <= TO_DATE(''2017-01-01'', ''YYYY-MM-DD'') ').EXTRACT ('ROWSET/ROW/*').GETCLOBVAL()  || 
'</System1>'AS XMLRETURNED FROM DUAL;
```

I then add parameters like this:

```
variable DATE_CREATEDMOSTRECENT1 varchar(1000)
exec :DATE_CREATEDMOSTRECENT1 :='2016-01-01';
variable DATE_CREATEDMOSTRECENT2 varchar(1000)
exec :DATE_CREATEDMOSTRECENT2 :='2017-01-01';

SELECT '<System1 MAPPINGID="13" URN="2441">' || DBMS_XMLGEN.GETXMLTYPE ('SELECT * from image_data where IMAGE_DATA.DATE_CREATED >= TO_DATE(:DATE_CREATEDMOSTRECENT1, ''YYYY-MM-DD'') 
AND IMAGE_DATA.DATE_CREATED <= TO_DATE(:DATE_CREATEDMOSTRECENT2, ''YYYY-MM-DD'') ').EXTRACT ('ROWSET/ROW/*').GETCLOBVAL()  || 
'</System1>'AS XMLRETURNED FROM DUAL;
```

There is an error with the second SQL statement saying the parameters are not declared.  What is the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both of your variable declarations produce, in SQL*Plus and SQL Developer, the error:

```
Usage: VAR[IABLE] [ <variable> [ NUMBER | CHAR | CHAR (n [CHAR|BYTE]) |
                    VARCHAR2 (n [CHAR|BYTE]) | NCHAR | NCHAR (n) |
                    NVARCHAR2 (n) | CLOB | NCLOB | BLOB | BFILE
                    REFCURSOR | BINARY_FLOAT | BINARY_DOUBLE ] ]
```

You can't use `VARCHAR`.

```
variable DATE_CREATEDMOSTRECENT1 varchar2(1000)
exec :DATE_CREATEDMOSTRECENT1 :='2016-01-01';

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

variable DATE_CREATEDMOSTRECENT2 varchar2(1000)
exec :DATE_CREATEDMOSTRECENT2 :='2017-01-01';

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.
```

You also currently have your bind variables embedded in string literals, so they won't be interpreted; you need to concatenate the binds:

```
SELECT '<System1 MAPPINGID="13" URN="2441">'
  || DBMS_XMLGEN.GETXMLTYPE ('SELECT * from image_data where IMAGE_DATA.DATE_CREATED >= TO_DATE('''
    || :DATE_CREATEDMOSTRECENT1 || ''', ''YYYY-MM-DD'') AND IMAGE_DATA.DATE_CREATED <= TO_DATE('''
    || :DATE_CREATEDMOSTRECENT2 || ''', ''YYYY-MM-DD'') ').EXTRACT ('ROWSET/ROW/*').GETCLOBVAL()
    || '</System1>'AS XMLRETURNED FROM DUAL;
```

with extra enclosing (escaped) single quotes around the bound strings too.